# How to create custom directives in LyX?

Tags: lyx, lyx-layouts

In LyX, there are special formatting directives such as "New Page" and "Page Break." They don't require any input and they have distinct appearance in the editor, such as having a horizontal dotted line and a nice centered label. For example:
[image]
This is neat and I'd like to create several new directives like this for my special layout. For example, I created several new paragraph styles to handle page numbering. Currently, they function as empty paragraphs representing a single latex command with no arguments. This is how they look like:
[image]
For reference, here's how I tried to create the "No Page Number" directive via paragraph style:

```
Style   "No Page Numbers"
    CopyStyle   Standard
    Category    "Page Numbers"
    LatexName   SetGobblePageNumbers
    LatexType   Command
    LabelFont
        Color   newpage
    EndFont
    Margin      First_Dynamic
    LabelString "No Page Numbers"
    LabelType   Static
    KeepEmpty   1
End
```

As I've said before, this is basically a new paragraph style that accepts empty input (i.e. `KeepEmpty`) and then when the file is compiled into Latex, it is being replaced by the latex command `SetGobblePageNumbers` which is defined in my special class. What I'd like to achieve is to create a custom directive for "No Page Numbers" like the one LyX does for "New Page." I managed to achieve something very close by centering the label via `LabelType Centered" but it still felt like a hack since it was still an empty paragraph and not a directive like LyX's "New Page."

In addition, I have another special style that I defined for a pilcrow symbol. I'd like to draw the dotted horizontal line around it the same way LyX displays "New Page." This is what I've achieved so far:
[image]

```
Style   "New Paragraph"
    CopyStyle   Standard
    LatexName   MarkNewParagraph
    LatexType   Command
    Align       Center
    AlignPossible   Center
    LabelFont
        Color   newpage
    EndFont
    Margin      First_Dynamic
    LabelString "¶"
    LabelType   Static
    KeepEmpty   1
End
```

This is a similar hack to my "No Page Number" paragraph style.

What I've done so far:

- I read and searched the LyX documentation for Customization and could not find anything beside paragraph styles and custom flex insets.
- I searched all files in LyX's installation directory for hints on how to achieve a similar document item like the "New Page" directive.
- I searched the internet, but found nothing.

Comment: +1 great question with helpful details and showing your effort. The new page inset does not work through LyX's custom layout mechanism. i.e., it's not defined in a "layout" file. It is defined at the C++ level. You can see the code here: https://git.lyx.org/?p=lyx.git;a=blob;f=src/insets/InsetNewpage.cpp;h=da944526321eb299cca73cc096ca368541d13749;hb=HEAD Note in there that the LaTeX is hardcoded in there. Also note the `InsetNewpage::draw()` routine, which means that the *display* code is also hardcoded.

Comment: You could look at LyX's Beamer `Pause` Style, which is defined in a layout file (`beamer.layout`). Is that be close enough to what you want? If not, you could take the long-run approach of making a feature request at https://www.lyx.org/trac/ with component "layout" essentially asking for the New Page's code to be factored out so that it could be defined in a layout. Or you could take the hackish approach of modifying the C++ code directly and compiling. If you want to do this, I could help you when I have time (maybe in a month).

Comment: @scottkosty, thanks for the comments! I think I'll try to make a new feature request. I really need LyX to let me define new special directives that aren't paragraphs.

Comment: @scottkosty, there's an error in LyX's trac website when trying to register a new account. It says: "No handler matched request to /register"

Comment: Ah good to know. We've had problems with spam bots registering so I think it may have been disabled. In that case, I suggest you send an email to lyx-devel@lists.lyx.org and reference this post. Perhaps what you want is possible and I just misunderstood. I don't know the layout features too well.